# Why would a pip installed package's __init__.py NOT have the canonical if __name__ == "__main__":?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am playing around with [pelican](http://github.com/getpelican/pelican), the static blog generator, which I have

- cloned from github

  $ git clone https://github.com/getpelican/pelican.git
- installed into my virtualenv as an editable package

  $ pip install -r dev_requirements.txt
   $ pip install -e .

Now I would like to run it, and debug it, using pycharm (and later in emacs)

I can't quite figure out how to do that!

I can run pelican from the command line.

```
$ pelican /blog/content -o /blog/public -s /blog/pelicanconf.py --relative_urls
```

But I cannot figure out how to run it from pycharm....

That is, I can set a breakpoint at `__init__.py:main()` but when pycharm runs `__init__.py` nothing happens.
Presumably pycharm runs `__init__` and it loads the various modules and then exits.

Until I add the canonical invocation trope:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

at the bottom of `__init__.py`

And then I can tell pycharm to run the `__init__.py` script and python enters the debugger at main() as I want.

---

(edited)
So my questions are

1. Why would a python package NOT have that trope at the end of its `__init__.py`?
2. How do I configure pycharm so that I can run and debug pelican (or similar python packages) from within it?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to run from pycharm or emacs. `pelican` gets installed as a binary program.

Comment: you can always just use `pelican.main()`

Comment: find file `pelican` on disk (Linux: `which pelican`) and open it in PyCharm - it normal python file (without extension) (maybe you will have to create project and add file to project before you can run it in PyCharm)

Comment: Why _should_ it? It's not ment to be run as a script. `pelican`s entry points are defined in its [setup.py](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/setup.py), which will cause the correct launch scripts to be generated in the `$prefix/bin` directory during install. Having modules inside a project being runnable as scripts usually causes more problems then it's worth, e.g. the module being imported twice, once as `__main__` and once as `module_name`, base path of the module added to sys.path (only the directory containing the _package_ should need to be on the path)...

Comment: I found file `pelican` and there is  `from pelican import main` and `main()` so `__init__.py` isn't use as main file but only as module so it doesn't need `__main__`

Comment: Thanks all, I appreciate the comments, though I don't quite understand most of them, but they all seem to miss my question: how do I debug pelican (or any similar package) using pycharm?

Answer (score 4):

The [`pelican/setup.py`](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/setup.py) defines several entrypoints:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'pelican = pelican:main',
        'pelican-import = pelican.tools.pelican_import:main',
        'pelican-quickstart = pelican.tools.pelican_quickstart:main',
        'pelican-themes = pelican.tools.pelican_themes:main'
    ]
}
```

I guess the first one tells that the function `pelican.main()` is called when you execute the `pelican` command.

So if you want to run pelican from PyCharm, you probably just have to run the `main()` function of the `pelican/__init__.py`

You can do that by:

- creating a simple script which just import and invoke the `pelican.main()` function
- run this script (in debug mode for debugging)

Comment: > So if you want to run pelican from PyCharm, you probably just have to run the main() function of the pelican/__init__.py

Yes, but how?

Comment: @Jerry: Creating a script which just invoke the `pelican.main()` function, then run the created script should do the trick.